# How do you push from nitrous.io to GIT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, github, nitrousio

I was following this guide [Nitrous to Heroku Guide](http://help.nitrous.io/heroku/)

It describes the process to fork a git repo but I want to push my directory of stuff to Git and then to Heroku. Well I really wanted to just push my stuff to Heroku. Argghh now I am lost.

So either push directly to Heroku or to Git and then on to Heroku.

Tutorial links always welcome if I have missed something.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will need to add two remotes within the same project.

Initiate your project for Git

```
$ git init
```

To add Github remote to your project and push:

```
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
# Set a new remote

$ git remote -v
# Verify new remote
# origin  https://github.com/user/repo.git (fetch)
# origin  https://github.com/user/repo.git (push)

$ git add .
$ git commit -m "initial commit"
$ git push origin master
```

To create a new Heroku project and push the remote to your project:

```
$ heroku create

$ git remote -v
# Verify new remote (you will see heroku and origin now
# heroku     git@heroku.com:falling-wind-1624.git (fetch)
# heroku     git@heroku.com:falling-wind-1624.git (push)
# origin  https://github.com/user/repo.git (fetch)
# origin  https://github.com/user/repo.git (push)

$ git push heroku master
```

This is a standard strategy which you will everytime want to git add, commit, and then push to both `origin master` (Github) and `heroku master` (Heroku).

Comment: A more complete answer than mine. +1

Answer (score 2):

If you have local data on your Nitrous Box, which isn't yet a git repo, what you need to do is:

```
cd /path/to/stuff
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Make stuff into a git repo"
```

From there, you can follow the steps described in the [tutorial you mention in your question](http://help.nitrous.io/heroku/), except for step 7: you don't need to clone a repo, since you just created one.