# Using Github with Nitrous.io

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, nitrousio

https://www.nitrous.io/join/GtIJ6P6P2WA

Trying to figure out what would be the best settings to setup a rails 4 app on nitrous.io and use github to back it up.

Comment: You can follow the instructions here and add your keys to Github: http://help.nitrous.io/github-add-key/

Answer (score 2):

After adding your SSH key from  http://help.nitrous.io/github-add-key/

Set up a new repo on github https://github.com/new

Then follow the steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18876028/682288 (Git part, not hte Heroku part) to create a remote origin pointing to your GitHub repo. and `git push origin master`